# Will switching Google Analytics account hurt SEO?

Tags: seo

I'm in a situation where my company does not have access to its analytics account nor the account recovery email address.

We are concerned about the impact changing accounts will have since this has been in place for years.  At the same time, we need access to the data.

Answer (score 1):

There is no evidence as of yet that supports the theory that Google uses Webmaster Tools/Analytics registration data in their ranking algorithms. While Google has changed their privacy policy to say that data can be shared between services no offical statement has been made about the usage of Analytics data including registration/account details.

Most people have this type of question when they suspect Google know that they run multiple sites in the same niche to dominate rankings, there is little to no evidence to support this theory either.

I believe that changing analytics account would absolutely have no effect on your rankings as I've never seen, heard or read evidence to support what your suspect.

Answer (score 0):

Changing accounts *shouldn't* affect your rankings at all.

That said, you will lose years worth of Analytics data, data which is very valuable for SEO strategies and tactics, what products people purchase (if the site is e-Commerce) and that data is gold if you plan on doing any PPC campaigns in the future.

I would do everything possible to retain the current account data before pulling the plug on the original account. Even if you can get in touch with someone who does have access to the data, they'd just need to add another user to the account as an Administrator, and you'd have access to your data again.